# Group by two columns where values may be switched

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, aggregate

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Start | End | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | 50 |
| X | Z | 100 |
| Y | Z | 50 |
| Y | X | 100 |

I am trying to group by pairs "Start" --> "End", where values may be switched. I'm calculating the sum of "Total". The result would look like this:

| Start | End | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | Y | 150 |
| X | Z | 100 |
| Y | Z | 50 |

X --> Y and Y --> X are equivalent and I want to sum the both under X --> Y.

I am quite stumped with this problem, and I am not even sure how to proceed conceptually with this. My current code gives me one direction, but how do I combine both directions?

```py
df2 = df.groupBy("Start", "End").sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge 'Start' and 'End' columns into `array` and then aggregate.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('X', 'Y', 50),
     ('X', 'Z', 100),
     ('Y', 'Z', 50),
     ('Y', 'X', 100)],
    ['Start', 'End', 'Total'])
```

Script:

```py
arr = F.array_sort(F.array('Start', 'End'))
df = df.groupBy(arr[0].alias('Start'), arr[1].alias('End')).agg(
    F.sum('Total').alias('Total')
)
df.show()
# +-----+---+-----+
# |Start|End|Total|
# +-----+---+-----+
# |    X|  Y|  150|
# |    X|  Z|  100|
# |    Y|  Z|   50|
# +-----+---+-----+
```

Comment: Ahh the trick was to turn it  into arrays thank you very much!

Comment: I'm getting an error here now that is confusing.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but here is the stack trace (trimmed to fit)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: expression '`Start`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;
```

Comment: I need to see your code to debug this. I'll try to guess that you tried adding more columns into the `agg`. If you try to add more expressions into `agg`, they all must have some aggregation function applied, because whatever column you add there, it will originally consist of several rows grouped by whatever you applied in `groupBy`. So you need a function which could choose/create one value out those several rows.